# How can I order this texts + list in SwiftUi?

Tags: list, text, swiftui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV1Xc.png)

Hi, I'm trying to make the ui like in the picture above, but I'm failing at it right now, I would like to have the text under "German" as a list with a maximum of 3 items, the text should also be arranged evenly, I've been trying to do it for a while, but unfortunately I'm not that familiar with SwiftUi yet :)

```
HStack{
            Group{
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        Text("Deutsch:")
                            .font(Font.custom("Jua-Regular", size: 22))
                            .padding(12.0)
                        
                    }
                    
                    VStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Text("- Lesen")
                            .font(Font.custom("Jua-Regular", size: 18))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("- Ab beende")
                            .font(Font.custom("Jua-Regular", size: 18))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("- Gedicht lernen")
                            .font(Font.custom("Jua-Regular", size: 18))
                        Spacer()
                       
                    }
                   
                    
                   
                }
            }
            .background(Color(red: 0.6039215686274509, green: 0.788235294117647, blue: 0.8901960784313725))
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .padding(22)
            Spacer()
            
            Group{
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        Text("Musik")
                            .font(Font.custom("Jua-Regular", size: 22))
                            .padding(12.0)
                        
                    }
                    
                    VStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Text("- Singen")
                            .font(Font.custom("Jua-Regular", size: 18))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("- Vortrag")
                            .font(Font.custom("Jua-Regular", size: 18))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("- Mozart lernen Lebenslauf!")
                            .font(Font.custom("Jua-Regular", size: 18))
                        Spacer()
                       
                    }
                   
                    
                   
                }
            }
            .background(Color(red: 0.6039215686274509, green: 0.788235294117647, blue: 0.8901960784313725))
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .padding(22)
            Spacer()
                
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: I read again your question and saw your picture. What are wrong with the picture that are not like you want? I'm assuming this data are not static on the SwiftUI and coming from the ViewModel now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you are doing the UI static, this should be static. Exactly like you wrote. This is probably a Proof of Concept, in this case you should have a ViewController managing the data. So put the data into a List and call sorted() on the List. Before pass to the view. If you have no idea what I'm talking about look for MVVM, there are good materials out there simple enough to understand and follow. In the Apple's website (developer.apple.com) there is a MVVM/SwiftUI example App. Keep in mind that Apple's examples and codes are ALWAYS a little bit behind, so you may have to start with the provided code or keep attention to what target you should be using. Probably iOS 14.0.